# updating listview after inserting row via content provider

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-contentprovider

I am using custom `ContentProvider` to insert and query the sqlite database in android. when i query the database i am populating data over listview. but the issue is when i insert the row i want to update the listview also.

i have created custom adapter by extending `CursorAdapter` and listening to `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`  , now when when i am inserting row by `context.getContentResolver().insert()` function , i want to update the listview.

i have tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after inserting the row but listview is not getting updated.

the only option i saw is `restartLoader()` is there anyother wat to update the listview ?

this is my insert code

```
context.getContentResolver().insert(

                ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.withAppendedPath(Columns.CONTENT_URI,


                                            Columns.INSERT_LOGS ), 

                                            Columns.LOGS),

                values);
```

i am inserting the logs of application and showing into listview

here is the code inside content provider

```
if(rowId > 0 ){


                Uri insertUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Columns.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
                Log.e("inserted  " , rowId+"");

                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertUri,null);
                return insertUri;

            }
```

Comment: show what what your insert method of the ContentProvider looks like. you shouldnt have to use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged when using Loaders

Comment: if i add any row dynamically then my listview is not getting updated

Comment: like I said post your code for your insert method in your content provider just as an example

Comment: see the updates please

Comment: Have you looked these 2 lines in Example? It's done what you do, don't you?  `long id = db.insert(CountriesDb.SQLITE_TABLE, null, values);
  getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`

Comment: There it's notified the ContentResolver and what you want is, that your associated adapter to ListView get the Changes from DB, is it like this?

Comment: yeah want to update ListView adapter

Comment: that looks correct the `getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertUri,null);` is what should be refreshing your list are you sure the rowId not 0

Comment: In the 2nd Link you can see how `CursorLoader` works, what you' need would be `public void onLoadFinished(

      Loader<Cursor> loader,

      Cursor cursor) {

   ((SimpleCursorAdapter)this.getListAdapter()).swapCursor(cursor);

}
`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can see how works [this example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html), because it's also based on `Loaders`.

[Please take a look at it too.](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)

I had troubles like you and the problem was how I did.

It was right like this.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    ...
    adapter.swap(cursor)
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.SetAdapter(dataAdapter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: nope this is not the solution as `onLoadFinished` called only once and swap method already updating the listview so no need to call notifyDataStateChanged and setting adapter again

Comment: Of course, that's no direct solution, you'd need to modify but that could lead you to better Understanding. That was my objective. Kind Regards